# How to prove existence of a function with estimategas

Tags: web3js

How can I prove the existence of a function in a smart contract with the EstimateGas ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to use `estimateGas` to determine in all cases the presence of a function.

If a function is not present it will invoke the fallback function. If it doesn't fail it will appear the function is working, but there's no function at all.

Other functions require specific parameters to work and they will fail if you do not send correct ones.

For some cases, for example if you suspect a contract to be an ERC20, you can check for specific functions like `balanceOf`, `decimals` etc.

Comment: can you provide a snippet for how to "check for specific functions like `balanceof`, `decimals` etc."? Is it simply `if (some_address.some_nonexistent_function == 0) { // now we know this function doesn't exist }`? And conversely are we 100% guaranteed for `if (some_address.some_nonexistent_function != 0) { // it must exist! }` to be true?

Comment: @almel Call `name()` would be `const tokenName = await contract.methods.name()`. Now if tokenName is some sensible string the contract might be a token, but you have no guarantee. Calling additional methods like decimals, symbol or balanceOf might give more confidance but never the certainity.

Answer (score 0):

I put estimateGas instead of .send or .call in the function and it works. 
Source: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.1/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call

Object: The transaction object:

Array - arguments: The arguments passed to the method before. They can be changed.
Function - call: Will call the “constant” method and execute its smart contract method in the EVM without sending a transaction (Can’t alter the smart contract state).
Function - send: Will send a transaction to the smart contract and execute its method (Can alter the smart contract state).
Function - estimateGas: Will estimate the gas used when the method would be executed on chain.